# Por que é importante remover o X-Powered-by dos headers de resposta? Como remover?

Tags: php, segurança, http-headers

Por que é importante remover o `X-Powered-By` dos cabeçalhos de resposta?

Isso impede alguma tipo de ataque, ou evita "informação privilegiada" ao atacante?

Exemplo:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
```

E quais são as maneiras possíveis, no PHP, de removê-los?

Comment: no php.ini , é recomendável desativar usando expose_php = Off... o motivo é evitar expor a tecnologia usada no servidor. Evita pessoas má intencionadas a procurar meios de hackear o server. Você pode inclusive manipular a informação, trocando para outra linguagem que não tenha nada a ver, assim deixa o "hacker" confuso, tentando burlar algo que não existe.   A desvantagem em bloquear a informação é para motores de busca que coletam esses dados para estatísticas. Com essa informação que sabemos +- a quantidade de servidores com PHP, ASP, JSP e por aí vai..

Comment: Uma pergunta adiconal, se alguém poder/souver responder: é possível desativar ou alterar esse cabeçalho pelo `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esse tipo de `header` é conhecido como [`ServerTokens`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens)/[`ServerSignature`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serversignature), ele revela informações do servidor como: nome, versão, tecnologia e em alguns casos até o sistema operacional.

O seu `header` em especifico (*`X-Powered-By`*) fornece informações da tecnologia que normalmente é `ASP.NET` ou `PHP`, no seu caso também mostra que esta rodando em um `ubuntu`, mas essa informação é bônus já que esta na versão/compilação do php.

Um outro `header` que também devemos estar atento é o `Server`, ele mostra nome e versão do servidor como `Ningx`, `Apache`, `Microsoft-IIS`.

Você também pode ter esse tipo de informação sendo exibida em telas de erro do servidor como mostrado nesta imagem abaixo de `Erro 404`, então depois de remover esse `header` vale apena verificar a pagina de erro.

[image: imagem - erro 404]

**Por que é recomendado remover essa informação?**
Como ela revela informações do servidor isso também acaba *(quase que sem querer)* expondo as vulnerabilidades conhecidas do servidor/sistema/tecnologia, facilitando o trabalho de uma pessoa que esta com a intenção de atacar seu servidor e algumas vezes até atraindo esse tipo de pessoa.
<sub>Alguns sites que mostram vulnerabilidades [https://nvd.nist.gov](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/search/results?form_type=Basic&results_type=overview&query=apache+2.4.18&search_type=all), [https://www.cvedetails.com](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-241078/Apache-Http-Server-2.4.18.html), [https://www.exploit-db.com](https://www.exploit-db.com/search?q=apache+2.4)</sub>

**Isso impede alguma tipo de ataque, ou evita "informação privilegiada" ao atacante?**
Isso não impede nenhum ataque. Mas um atacante com essas informações pode procurar por vulnerabilidades conhecidas e isso vai facilitar a vida dele e aumentar sua chance de ter sucesso com o ataque.

**É possível desativar ou alterar esse cabeçalho pelo `.htaccess`?***
Para remover um `header` pelo `.htaccess` você precisa adicionar o seguinte config `Header unset <nome do header>` ou `Header always unset <nome do header>`. Nesse caso ficando como mostrado abaixo.

```
Header always unset X-Powered-By
```

*[nota]*

1. *O mais recomendado é configurar o `php.ini` e o servidor para não retornar essas informações ao cliente.*
2. *Eu não testei esse método, logo não sei se ele consegue remover esse `header`*

<sub>*Pergunta feita no comentário da pergunta por **Guilherme Costamilam**</sub>

---

## Removendo o header `X-Powered-By`

#### PHP

No `php` você terá que editar o arquivo `php.ini` e alterar o valor de `expose_php = On` para **`expose_php = Off`**, após alterar não se esqueça de restarta o `php`.

<sub>outra opção é você remover/alterar a informação pelo seu script `php`, como por exemplo colocar um dos comando abaixo na sua `index.php`.</sub>

```
header('X-Powered-By: MeuServer');
header_remove( 'X-Powered-By' )
```

<sub>***[IMPORTANTE]** Se você optar por remover o header dessa forma, ou seja com esse comando acima, você só vai conseguir remover esse header em arquivos que você alterou, isso significa que o servidor vai continuar respondendo esse header, ou seja, **a melhor opção é configurar no php.ini***</sub>

---

## Removendo o header `Server`

#### Apache2

No `apache2` você consegue desativar esse tipo de `header` alterando ou adicionando no final do arquivo `apache2.conf` as seguintes configurações

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

Após alterar o arquivo de configuração não se esqueça de restartar o serviço do `apache2`, para isso você pode utilizar **um** dos comandos abaixo para `linux`.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

#### Nginx

No `nginx` você vai precisar instalar o `nginx-extras` para alterar `headers` desse tipo

```
sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

*Comando de instalação caso você esteja utilizando **ubuntu**/**debian**

e adicionar a configuração ao arquivo `nginx.conf` dentro de `http{`

```
#more_set_headers "Server: MeuServer"; # Modifica o Header Server
more_clear_headers Server; # Remove o Header Server
server_tokens off; # Não retornar versão do nginx e sistema operacional
```

Após alterar o arquivo não se esqueça de restartar o serviço do `nginx`, para isso você pode utilizar o comando do `linux` abaixo.

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

> #### IIS e ASP.NET
>
> <sup>O site abaixo esta em inglês e possui mais informações sobre esses headers e como remover se você estiver utilizando `IIS`, `ASP.NET` com um tutorial com imagens.</sup>
> **Hardening your HTTP response headers** - [scotthelme.co.uk](https://scotthelme.co.uk/hardening-your-http-response-headers/#server)

---

> #### Links úteis
>
> <sup>Alguns links úteis que ajudam a analisar as configuração de `headers` e de `SSL` de seu servidor:</sup>
> **Analise de headers** - [securityheaders.com](https://securityheaders.com/)
> **Analise de ssl** - [ssllabs.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)

Answer (score 14):

Não impede nem evita, na verdade, creio que passe informações além do necessário informando o ambiente. Eu não uso esse header como fator de segurança. Você pode removê-lo ou no `INI` ou no próprio `PHP`.

**Removendo pelo `INI`** : `expose_php = Off`

**Removendo pelo `PHP`** : `header_remove( 'X-Powered-By' )`

<sub>A função [header_remove](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php) está disponível para *PHP 5 >= 5.3.0*</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Veja este artigo já antigo e ainda muito útil:

[Apache Tips & Tricks: Hide PHP Version (X-Powered-By)](http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/16/apache-tips-tricks-hide-php-version-x-powered-by/)

Gostaria ainda adicionar que no sistemas que desenvolvo ou participo este elemento do cabeçalho é sempre mascarado ou retirado. Digo mascarado com o nome do domínio por exemplo.

Isto porque se trata de uma informação que pode trazer insegurança. Ou seja, mascarar o seu conteúdo por si só não coloca o sistema mais seguro apenas impede 
o host remoto de perceber o sistema e a versão do `PHP` que está a ser executada.

Todos sabemos que todas as versões em qualquer software tem as suas falhas e todas são documentadas ao longo do tempo de vida da mesma e o `PHP` não é excepção.

A análise deste tipo de informação permite perceber quais as falhas que essa versão especificamente terá e daí pode partir algumas falhas de segurança com consequentes ataques.

ACTUALIZAÇÃO:
Convém ainda dizer que nos elementos `CSS`, `JS` ou `imagens` pertencentes a uma página que "mascare" este elemento de cabeçalho este pode ser visualizado normalmente, pelo que se a opção for a de mascarar o conteúdo deste elemento de cabeçalho o mesmo deve de ser realizado para quaisquer tipo de elementos que requerem `requests` autónomos.